# Fill area between two connected components in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fill

I have a binary image that represents a number in MATLAB:

[image: image description]

I'd like to fill all the digits. The desired result is:

[image]

The only thing I found was the `imfill` function, but that wasn't really helpfull since I've lost my inner data (the 9's inner circle for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how to distinguish the holes from the digits. A possible ad hoc solution is  filtering them by the area of the pixels inside.

```
function SolveSoProblem()

    I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUvif.png');

    %Fill all the holes 
    F = imfill(I,'holes');

    %Find all the small ones,and mark their edges in the image
    bw = bwlabel(I);
    rp = regionprops(bw,'FilledArea','PixelIdxList');
    indexesOfHoles = [rp.FilledArea]<150;   
    pixelsNotToFill = vertcat(rp(indexesOfHoles).PixelIdxList); 
    F(pixelsNotToFill) = 0;
    figure;imshow(F);

    %Remove the inner area
    bw1 = bwlabel(F,4);
    rp = regionprops(bw1,'FilledArea','PixelIdxList');
    indexesOfHoles1 = [rp.FilledArea]<150;
    pixelListToRemove = vertcat(rp(indexesOfHoles1).PixelIdxList);
    F(pixelListToRemove) = 0;

    figure;imshow(F);
end
```

After **step(1)**:

[image]

After **step(2)**:

[image]

Comment: Impressive solution.
Thanks a lot!!
The only little thing I changed was to remove objects which space is smaller than 2 pct of the image and it works great!!

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use the [BWBOUNDARIES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) function, which:

> traces the exterior boundaries of objects, as well as boundaries of
>   holes inside these objects

That information is contained in the fourth output `A`, an adjacency matrix that  represents the parent-child-hole dependencies.

```
%# read binary image
bw = imread('SUvif.png');

%# find all boundaries
[B,L,N,A] = bwboundaries(bw, 8, 'holes');

%# exclude inner holes
[r,~] = find(A(:,N+1:end));        %# find inner boundaries that enclose stuff
[rr,~] = find(A(:,r));                      %# stuff they enclose
idx = setdiff(1:numel(B), [r(:);rr(:)]);    %# exclude both
bw2 = ismember(L,idx);                      %# filled image

%# compare results
subplot(311), imshow(bw), title('original')
subplot(312), imshow( imfill(bw,'holes') ), title('imfill')
subplot(313), imshow(bw2), title('bwboundaries')
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I had the feeling that there must be a Matlab function that does it, but didn't know it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the top-left pixel is always outside the regions to filled:

Work across the top line, copying pixels to the output image

When you come to a white pixel followed by a black pixel in the input image, start setting white pixels in the output image, until you come to black pixel followed by a white pixel.

Comment: @EitanT: true enough - I was going on the sample provided.

Comment: @MartinThompson the images are binary ones, so the comment you received is irrelevant.